# If loop not working in perl

Tags: perl, if-statement

Please take a look at this script and suggest possible solutions..

```
my $otext = 'ABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDE'; 
my $len   = length($otext);
print "length of string is:\n".$len;
$n = 1;

if ($n == 1) {

    if (substr($otext, -1, 1) eq "E") {

        if ($len >= 3) {

            if ($len == 3) {

                $len1 = 2 * $len - 1; 
                $len2 = 3 * $len - 2; 
            }
            else {

                $len1 = 2*$len-1; 
                $len2 = 3*$len-3;
            }
        }
        else {

             $len1 = 0;
             $len2 = 0;     
        }   
        print "Length-1 is:". $len1;
        print "Length-2 is:" .$len2;
    }
}
else { 

    print "\n It's else loop ";
}
```

Comment: Please don't make us guess at what this code should do and how it fails. One hint, though: `if` is not a loop construct (not even in Perl, AFAIK).

Comment: First of all, and `if` block is not a loop. Second, what is the problem? How is it not working? Is there an error message? What do you want to achieve? Also, your code is not compiling. Add `use strict` and `use warnings` and you'll see what the problem is.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answers, I would like to suggest some improvements to your code

#### Eliminate Dead Code

```
my $n = 1;
if ($n == 1) {
  # Code 1
} else {
  # Code 2
}
```

will *always* run Code 1.

#### Avoid C-isms

```
substr($otext,-1,1) eq "E"
```

tests if the last character is an `E`. In Perl, this can written much nicer with regexes:

```
$otext =~ /E$/
```

The `$` denotes the end of the string in regexes.

#### Simplify Your Logic

You have this construct:

```
if ($len >= 3) {
  if ($len == 3) {
    # Code 1
  } else {
    # Code 2
  }
} else {
  # Code 3
}
```

This is exactly equal to

```
if ($len == 3) {
  # Code 1
} elsif ($len > 3) {
  # Code 2
} else {
  # Code
}
```

#### Declare Your Variables

Always declare your variables with `my` in the outermost scope where they are used. The only exception to this rule is (a) when you're writing a quick one-liner or (b) you have a *very* good reason to use globals.

#### Put Newlines Where They Belong

I believe that this code

```
  print "Length-1 is:". $len1;
  print "Length-2 is:" .$len2;
```

is intended to produce output like

```
Length-1 is: 0
Length-2 is: 0
```

and not

```
Length-1 is:0Length-2 is:0
```

I'd interpolate your variables `$len1` and `$len2` into the string, append newlines, and include a space:

```
  print "Length-1 is: $len1\n";
  print "Length-2 is: $len2\n";
```

Comment: +1 for covering all the aspects of the code.. Great :)

Answer (score 3):

On the top-level you have used your if as `if (n == 1)`, that will not compile.. Your variable should be prefixed with a `$` if its a scalar..  So, use `if($n == 1)`

Also, `if` is not a loop, its a construct..

Answer (score 2):

`n` should be `$n` in the `if` condition:

```
if ($n==1){
```